# Unable to import to remote mongodb using mongoimport

Tags: linux, mongodb, mongo-shell, mongoimport, mongoexport

I want to use `mongoexport` to export my local mongodb documents to a json file and then use `mongoimport` to upload the json file to my remote mongodb.

I got the first part working with this command `mongoexport -c collection -d db --jsonArray -q '{"$and":[{"session_id": "session"},{"data.component": "component"}]}' --out /home/user/mongo_export.json -u "username" -p "password" --authenticationDatabase "admin"`.

However, when I tried using this command: `mongoimport --host hostname --port 27017 -c collection -d db --file /home/user/mongo_export.json`, I got this error `error connecting to host: could not connect to server: connection() : dial tcp: i/o timeout`.

I checked my connection by running `mongosh hostname` in terminal and it seemed to connect to the remote db: [mongosh output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdL7E.jpg). I also was able to connect to the remote db through mongodb-compass.

My colleague was able to use the exact same command to import to my remote db so I really don't know what is wrong...

Comment: As an option, you can import from Compass.

Comment: I'm guessing they'd want to automate the process via a script or something. Not sure if there's a way to automate compass queries via bash script.